# running time for return in calculating time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Suppose we have this simple `Java` method:

```
public static int S(int list[],int n) {
    if (n==1) {
        return list[1];
    } else {
        return (list[n] + S(list, n-1));
    }
}
```

I want to calculate the `time complexity` of `S` method. But I am in doubt in about second `return`. Which have I to consider as running time:

- `T(n) = T(n-1) + 3`: `T(n-1)` + `1` time for `return` itself + `1` time for calling `list[n]` + `1` time for `+` operation
- `T(n) = T(n-1) + 2`: `T(n-1)` + `1` time for `return` itself + `1` time for `+` operation
- `T(n) = T(n-1) + 2`: `T(n-1)` + `1` time for calling `list[n]` + `1` time for `+` operation
- `T(n) = T(n-1) + 1`: `T(n-1)` + `1` time for `+` operation

Answer (score 0):

It's practically impossible to calculate the exact time complexity in terms of number of operations without knowing how the whole language is implemented as well as your computer's architecture, that's why people are mostly interested in [asymptotic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_computational_complexity).

In your example, you can merge all of them by saying it's a constant number of operation taking a constant time, so the recurrence relation you are looking for will be `T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1)`, which will yield `T(n)=O(n)`. Note that all solutions of your equations (`T(n)=n, 2n, 3n`) were also linear, so a `O(n)` time, so the simplification indeed captures all of them.